# How to control Zoom In and Zoom Out in Windows form Chart by adding Zoom buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

How to control Zoom In and Zoom Out in Windows Forms Chart by adding ZoomIn and ZoomOut button

```
chart1.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
```

Answer (score 3):

Zoom-in button:

```
Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
ax.ScaleView.Size = double.IsNaN(ax.ScaleView.Size)?   
                    (ax.Maximum - ax.Minimum) / 2 : ax.ScaleView.Size /= 2;
```

Zoom-out:

```
Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
ax.ScaleView.Size = double.IsNaN(ax.ScaleView.Size)?   
                    ax.Maximum : ax.ScaleView.Size *= 2;
if (ax.ScaleView.Size > ax.Maximum - ax.Minimum)
{
    ax.ScaleView.Size = ax.Maximum;
    ax.ScaleView.Position = 0;
}
```